# filtering table results using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, checkbox, filtering

I'm working on a php online shop website using codeigniter framework and i want to be able to filter my table results using checkboxes with ajax

**view:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="acer">  


<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="lenovo">    

<input type="checkbox" name="pret" value="1000">   



 <table>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($laptops_toate as $laptops_all) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="http://localhost:82/ci/images/emag/<?php echo $laptops_all->file ?>"></td>
                <td><p>Laptop <?php echo $laptops_all->brand ?> </p>
                </td>


            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function laptops()
{

    $filter = array(
        'pret' => $this->input->get('pret'),
        'brand' =>$this->input->get('brand')
    );

    $data['laptops_toate'] = $this->emag_model->laptops_toate_grid($filter);

    $this->renders('emag/laptops', $data);
}
```

**model:**

```
 public function laptops_toate_grid($filter = null){
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('laptop_notebook');
   // $query = $this->db->get('laptop_notebook')->result();
   // return $query;
    if($filter['brand']){
        $this->db->where('brand', $filter['brand']);
    }
    if($filter['pret']){
        $this->db->where('pret', $filter['pret']);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    return $query;

}
```

The problem is now at the ajax code, i don't know how to send the data filter to the server in order to receive the success function.

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<script>
$("input[checkbox]").change(function(){
               $.ajax({
            url: route,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                    $("tbody").empty();
                    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+
                    "Laptop "+element.brand+""+
                    "</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        });
```

Controller:

```
 public function laptops()
{

$filter = array(
    'pret' => $this->input->get('pret'),
    'brand' =>$this->input->get('brand')
);

echo json_encode($this->emag_model->laptops_toate_grid($filter));
}
```

Now just do console.log(data); first inside the $.each() to see what your array looks like.

Comment: I also recommend changing the code in the view for a better overview, this is just personal prefference.

Instead of :

    <?php foreach($variable as var) {?>
        <html comes here>
    <?php } ?>

Use : 

    <?php foreach($variable as var) : ?>
  <html comes here>
    <?php endforeach(); ?>

Sure it's not as fast, but the preformance loss is really low and with bigger views its easier to see where loops and if's end.

Again just my personal opinion

Comment: That is odd, here is a link of how I usually use PHP inside my HTML http://puu.sh/hTfix/d5994b14e3.png

Comment: i agree with you about the foreach thing but the main problem remains at ajax :|, somehow,using dataType: 'json' doesn't do anything in my console

Comment: @killstreet - Best solution.